# Select person in a table having a specific value but not having another value for same id

Tags: sql, db2

I tried for hours and read many posts but I still can't figure out how to handle this request:

I have a table like this:

```
+------+------+------+
|PERSON|TRTYPE| ID   |
+------+------+------+
|JERRY | I    |   2  |
+------+------+------+
|JERRY | U    |   2  |
+------+------+------+
|TOM   | U    |   2  |
+------+------+------+
|SPIKE | I    |   3  |
+------+------+------+
|SPIKE | U    |   3  |
+------+------+------+
```

I would like to select the **PERSON, ID** that has a TRTYPE of U for an ID but he does not have a TRYPE of I for that same ID.

The output should be something like:

```
+------+------+
|PERSON| ID   |
+------+------+
|TOM   | U    |
+------+------+
```

As TOM is the only person who has performed a transtype of U on an ID on which he did not perform a TRTYPE of I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use aggregation and `having`:

```
select person, id
from mytable
where trtype in ('I', 'U')
group by person, id
having min(trtype) = max(trtype) and min(trtype) = 'U'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use NOT EXISTS like in the below query

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable A WHERE A.TRTYPE ='U'
AND NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT 1 FROM yourtable T WHERE T.TRTYPE ='I'
AND T.PERSON=A.PERSON AND T.ID=A.ID
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is called [table_1],

```
SELECT [PERSON], [ID] FROM [table_1] t1
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [table_1] t2 WHERE t2.[PERSON] = t1.[PERSON] AND t2.[TRTYPE] = ‘I’) = 0
```

Comment: This table is huge. I believe calling count on it will be slow

Answer (score 0):

You could use Common Table Expression to break your logic and acheive the result as follows

```
with cte as(select * from table where trptype in ('U')) 
select * from cte where cte.id not in (select distinct cte.id from cte where cte.trptype in ('I'))
```